# VS2013 with Git Missing Version Control for Web Site Project

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, solution-explorer, team-explorer-everywhere

Using VS2013 with Git.
Under a our repository folder we have 3 projects:
2 Class Library projects.
1 Web Site project.
All three are in a Solution in VS2013.
In the Solution Explorer a we see source control icons (lockers etc.) and right click menu commands for the 2 Class Library projects, but none of this for the Web Site Project.
When we change a file in the Web Project we do see the change tracking on the Team Explorer and can do all the source control actions there.
So why there is no version control on the Solution Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
DID 2 changes:
1. Added new project to solution.
2. Installed the VS 2013 Update 3.

Do not know which one of them or both did it, but it is fixed now.